Reworking the sorting algorithm for a three-dimensional array
I've been able to convert this algorithm to sort a three-dimensional array. It should sort P two-dimensional matrices by columns “through” the whole array, not each column separately.
The whole program code would not fit here, so I attach a small demo version. The algorithm for the vector is working, there are no errors in it.
Can anyone help me? I sincerely do not understand what the error can be.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

clock_t Select8_3D(int*** A, int P, int M, int N) {
    int Li, Ri, Lj, Rj, imin, imax, jmin, jmax, temp;

    clock_t time_start, time_stop;
    time_start = clock();

    for (int k = 0; k < P; k++) {

        Lj = 0;
        Rj = N - 1;

        while (Lj < Rj) {

            jmin = Lj;
            jmax = Lj;

            Li = 0;
            Ri = M - 1;

            while (Li < M) {
                imin = Li;
                imax = Li;

                // search for minimum and maximum for the leftmost column 
                for (int i = Li + 1; i < M; i++) {
                    if (A[k][i][jmin] < A[k][imin][jmin]) {
                        imin = i;
                    }
                    else if (A[k][i][jmin] > A[k][imax][jmin]) {
                        imax = i;
                    }
                }

                // search for minimum and maximum for rectangular area
                for (int j = Lj + 1; j < Rj; j++) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
                        if (A[k][i][j] < A[k][imin][jmin]) {
                            imin = i;
                            jmin = j;
                        }
                        else if (A[k][i][j] > A[k][imax][jmax]) {
                            imax = i;
                            jmax = j;
                        }
                    }
                }


                // search for minimum and maximum for the rightmost column 
                for (int i = 0; i <= Ri; i++) {
                    if (A[k][i][Rj] < A[k][imin][jmin]) {
                        imin = i;
                        jmin = Rj;
                    }
                    else if (A[k][i][Rj] > A[k][imax][jmax]) {
                        imax = i;
                        jmax = Rj;
                    }
                }

                // repositioning of elements
                if (imin != Li && jmin != Lj) {
                    temp = A[k][imin][jmin];
                    A[k][imin][jmin] = A[k][Li][Lj];
                    A[k][Li][Lj] = temp;
                }

                if (imax != Ri && jmax != Rj) {
                    if (imax == Li && jmax == Lj) {
                        temp = A[k][imin][jmin];
                        A[k][imin][jmin] = A[k][Ri][Rj];
                        A[k][Ri][Rj] = temp;
                    }
                    else {
                        temp = A[k][imax][jmax];
                        A[k][imax][jmax] = A[k][Ri][Rj];
                        A[k][Ri][Rj] = temp;
                    }
                }

                Li += 1;
                Ri -= 1;
            }
            Lj += 1;
            Rj -= 1;
        }

    }

    time_stop = clock();
    return (time_stop - time_start);
}


void printMatrix(int*** A, int P, int M, int N) {
    for (int k = 0; k < P; ++k) {
        printf("matrix %d:\n", k + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
                printf("%d ", A[k][i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int P = 2; // number of “matrices”
    int M = 10; // number of lines
    int N = 10; // number of columns

    // Memory allocation and matrix initialization
    int*** A = (int***)malloc(P * sizeof(int**));
    for (int i = 0; i < P; ++i) {
        A[i] = (int**)malloc(M * sizeof(int*));
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
            A[i][j] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
            for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
                A[i][j][k] = rand() % 100; // случайные значения
            }
        }
    }

    // Output of initial matrices
    printf("Matrix before sorting:\n");
    printMatrix(A, P, M, N);

    // Algorithm call
    clock_t execution_time = Select8_3D(A, P, M, N);


    // Output of sorted matrices
    printf("\nSorted matrix:\n");
    printMatrix(A, P, M, N);

    // Memory release
    for (int i = 0; i < P; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
            free(A[i][j]);
        }
        free(A[i]);
    }
    free(A);

    return 0;
}

The way it works in my program:

How it should work:

Algorithm for vector:
clock_t Select8_1D(int* A, int N, int P) {
    int L, R, imin, imax, tmp;

    clock_t time_start, time_stop;
    time_start = clock();

    L = 0; R = N - 1;

    while (L < R) {
        imin = L; imax = L;

        for (int i = L + 1; i < R + 1; i++) {
            if (A[i] < A[imin]) {
                imin = i;
            }
            else if (A[i] > A[imax]) {
                imax = i;
            }
        }

        if (imin != L) {
            tmp = A[imin];
            A[imin] = A[L];
            A[L] = tmp;
        }

        if (imax != R) {
            if (imax == L) {
                tmp = A[imin];
                A[imin] = A[R];
                A[R] = tmp;
            }
            else {
                tmp = A[imax];
                A[imax] = A[R];
                A[R] = tmp;
            }
        }

        L = L + 1;
        R = R - 1;
    }
    time_stop = clock();
    return (time_stop - time_start) * P;
}


The way it works in my program:

Described above, but I'm just out of ideas already.

Er, I do not understand your sorting criteria.

sorry, i used translator to write this text. it has to sort all elemnts for a columns, like {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {3.6,9}. added result of another algorythm that works correctly as axample

It looks like you want all elements sorted by column, then by row, and then by matrix. Is that right?

this algorithm should sort all elements of the array in ascending order through the columns. Two bounds, left and right, are used to narrow the search area for the minimum and maximum numbers at each iteration of the loop. It first looks for the minimum and maximum number in the search area by comparing the indices to the elements on the boundaries, and then does permutations. But I have something going wrong, and the sorting is only partially correct.

Well, I'd just copy all the data in a plain array, sort it, and copy back the elements in the 3D one, filling the columns one by one, as needed, but it might not be what you lecturer is expecting.

It is easier for me to just show how to sort arbitrary data by arbitrary rules using a standard quicksort than it is to figure out how you thought your logic would work.
Note that indirection through pointers is not great for speed. But it does make it easier for me to think about it.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// All of our real work.
// Hiding data in context, and layout in compare/swap makes the algorithm easy.
void _qsort_any (int start, int end, void * context,
            int (*compare) (const void*, int, int),
            void (*swap) (const void*, int, int)) {
    int pivots_end, smalls_end, larges_start, mid_end;
    int last_compare;

    // Only need to sort if 2+ elements.
    if (1 < end - start) {
        if (3 < end - start) {
            // Use midpoint as pivot.
            (swap)(context, start, start + (end-start)/2);
        }

        // Start with 1 pivot, no smalls, lots of unsorted, nothing large.
        pivots_end = start + 1;
        smalls_end = pivots_end;
        larges_start = end;

        // Keep moving first unsorted into pivots, smalls, and larges.
        while (smalls_end < larges_start) {
            last_compare = (compare)(context, start, smalls_end);
            if (0 == last_compare) {
                // Add new pivot by swapping first small with this.
                (swap)(context, pivots_end, smalls_end);
                pivots_end++;
                smalls_end++;
            } else if (0 < last_compare) {
                // Found new large.
                larges_start--;
                (swap)(context, smalls_end, larges_start);
            } else {
                // Found new small.
                smalls_end++;
            }
        }

        // If we have smalls.
        if (pivots_end < smalls_end) {
            // We now have pivots, smalls, and larges. Move pivots to middle.
            mid_end = smalls_end;
            while (start < pivots_end) {
                pivots_end--;
                smalls_end--;
                (swap)(context, pivots_end, smalls_end);
            }
            // And now sort smalls.
            _qsort_any(start, smalls_end, context, compare, swap);
        }

        // Sort larges.
        if (1 < end - larges_start) {
            _qsort_any(larges_start, end, context, compare, swap);
        }
    }
}

// Where we enter the quicksort.
void qsort_any (int memb, void * context,
                int (*compare) (const void*, int, int),
                void (*swap) (const void*, int, int)) {
    _qsort_any(0, memb, context, compare, swap);
}

// The context we will use.
struct MatricesContext {
    int*** A;
    int P;
    int M;
    int N;
};

// Our comparison function.
int MatricesValueCompare(const void * raw_context, int i, int j) {
    int P, M, N, Mi, Ni, Mj, Nj, vi, vj;
    // Should always, always, always be the right type.
    const struct MatricesContext * context = (const struct MatricesContext *) raw_context;

    P = context->P;
    M = context->M;
    N = context->N;

    // Column first, then row, then matrix.
    Mi = i % M;
    i = (i - Mi) / M;
    Ni = i % N;
    i = (i - Ni) / N;
    vi = context->A[i][Mi][Ni];

    Mj = j % M;
    j = (j - Mj) / M;
    Nj = j % N;
    j = (j - Nj) / N;
    vj = context->A[j][Mj][Nj];

    if (vi < vj) {
        return 1;
    } else if (vj < vi) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

// Our swap function.
void MatricesValueSwap(const void * raw_context, int i, int j) {
    int P, M, N, Pi, Mi, Ni, Pj, Mj, Nj, tmp;
    const struct MatricesContext * context = (const struct MatricesContext *) raw_context;

    if (i != j) {
        P = context->P;
        M = context->M;
        N = context->N;

        // Column first, then row, then matrix.
        Mi = i % M;
        i = (i - Mi) / M;
        Ni = i % N;
        i = (i - Ni) / N;
        Pi = i;

        Mj = j % M;
        j = (j - Mj) / M;
        Nj = j % N;
        j = (j - Nj) / N;
        Pj = j;

        // Now we can swap them.
        tmp = context->A[Pi][Mi][Ni];
        context->A[Pi][Mi][Ni] = context->A[Pj][Mj][Nj];
        context->A[Pj][Mj][Nj] = tmp;
    }
}

// This was your Select8_3D.
clock_t Sort_3D(int*** A, int P, int M, int N) {
    struct MatricesContext context = {A, P, M, N};

    clock_t time_start, time_stop;
    time_start = clock();

    // And do the work.
    qsort_any(P*M*N, &context, MatricesValueCompare, MatricesValueSwap);

    time_stop = clock();
    return (time_stop - time_start);
}

void printMatrix(int*** A, int P, int M, int N) {
    for (int k = 0; k < P; ++k) {
        printf("matrix %d:\n", k + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
                printf("%3d ", A[k][i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}



int main() {
    int P = 2; // number of “matrices”
    int M = 10; // number of lines
    int N = 10; // number of columns

    // Memory allocation and matrix initialization
    int*** A = (int***)malloc(P * sizeof(int**));
    for (int i = 0; i < P; ++i) {
        A[i] = (int**)malloc(M * sizeof(int*));
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
            A[i][j] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
            for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
                A[i][j][k] = rand() % 100; // случайные значения
            }
        }
    }

    // Output of initial matrices
    printf("Matrix before sorting:\n");
    printMatrix(A, P, M, N);

    // Algorithm call
    clock_t execution_time = Sort_3D(A, P, M, N);


    // Output of sorted matrices
    printf("\nSorted matrix:\n");
    printMatrix(A, P, M, N);

    // Memory release
    for (int i = 0; i < P; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
            free(A[i][j]);
        }
        free(A[i]);
    }
    free(A);

    return 0;
}


Thanks. I like your solution, but I was given a term paper assignment to rework this algorithm in the original format. If I submit something like this, my work just won't be accepted.
